# Krangl: Count number of elements in column that are contained in another list

Tags: dataframe, kotlin

I'm using Krangl library because I want to do simple exploratory data analysis.
I want to count number of samples that are from some other array.
I have following code

```kotlin
    val df: DataFrame = dataFrameOf(
            "structure", "biome", "layer18")(
            "mansion", "dark_forest", "ocean",
            "mansion", "dark_forest", "dark_forest",
            "mansion", "dark_forest_hills", "dark_forest",
            "mansion", "dark_forest", "ocean",
            "temple", "desert", "desert"
    )

    val sum = df.summarize(
            "biome in dark forest" to {it["biome"].eq("dark_forest").count{ it } + it["biome"].eq("dark_forest_hills").count{ it }},
            "layer18 dark forest or ocean" to {it["biome"].eq("dark_forest").count{ it } + it["biome"].eq("ocean").count{ it }}
    )

    println(df)
    println(sum)
```

which outputs

```
A DataFrame: 5 x 3
    structure               biome       layer18
1     mansion         dark_forest         ocean
2     mansion         dark_forest   dark_forest
3     mansion   dark_forest_hills   dark_forest
4     mansion         dark_forest        plains
5      temple              desert        desert
A DataFrame: 1 x 2
    biome in dark forest   layer18 dark forest or ocean
1                      4                              3
```

but I don't like that I need to have expression for every element I want to check against. Because the list of values I want to compare against can have variable size.

In pure kotlin, I'd write

```kotlin
df["biome"].asStrings().map { it in listOf("dark_forest", "dark_forest_hills") }.map { if (it) 1 else 0 }.sum()
```

or

```kotlin
df["biome"].asStrings().sumBy { if(it in listOf("dark_forest", "dark_forest_hills")) 1 else 0 }
```

but I want to use krangl properly and idiomatically and jumping out and to krangl seems not right.

Also, in Pandas, I'd do sth. like `df['biome'].isin(["dark_forest", "dark_forest_hills"]).sum()` but I can't find such functionality in krangl.

How should I do it in krangl?

Comment: I have never used kranglr, but I am interested in the project and to follow it. Would a `filter` work? https://krangl.gitbook.io/docs/getting-started/data_manip#subset-your-records-with-filter . I am just guessing here but something like `df.filter { it["biome"].isMatching {setOf("dark_forest", "dark_forest_hills")}}` ?

Comment: I don't think it's right, it does not seem krangl understands passing set to isMatching, this is telling `Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in inline fun <reified T> DataCol.isMatching(missingAs: Boolean = ..., crossinline filter: T.() -> Boolean): BooleanArray
Please specify it explicitly.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```kotlin
df.filter { it["biome"].isMatching<String> { it as String in  setOf("dark_forest", "dark_forest_hill") } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer fails due to ClassCastException on the latest version of Krangl.

This could help somebody:

```
.isMatching<String> { indexOfAny(setOf("dark_forest", "dark_forest_hill")) != -1 })
```